# Why does the .NET runtime add underscores to my string?

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I store my application settings the C# way (`Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`). The settings are then stored by the C# runtime in the folder:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\My_Company_Name
```

The strange thing is that I entered "My Company Name" as the Company-property in Visual Studio (`[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company Name")]`).

So, where do the underscores come from? I've seen other apps creating folders **with** blanks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a `property` named "My Company Name". That is not a valid `member` name in C# so it is automatically transformed for you into a valid name: "My_Company_Name"

Same thing happens if you create a new project named "My Project". The default `namespace` of your project will not be "My Project" because its not valid. The default `namespace` VS will create for you will be "My_Project".

Comment: +1. Agree. Just adding quote `Each application setting must have a unique name; the name can be any combination of letters, numbers, or an underscore that does not start with a number, and cannot contain spaces` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)